# Stair well descent

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, estimation

I am trying to understand the science behind lowering a person down a flight of stairs on a sled. My tensile strength only says it can hold 250 pounds but I have seen it lower people that weigh 300 pounds.

Is there some equation out there to calculate the tension of a rope when lowering objects down an incline?

Let me know if I need to clarify more.

Comment: Take the gravitational force on the person and separate it into components parallel and perpendicular to the incline of the stairs. The normal force exerted by the stairs and the tension in the rope must be equal to the components of the gravitational force.

Answer (score 1):

Gravity pulls straight down. When you are at an incline, the force you need is lower (you know this from experience: pulling something up a steep slope is harder work than pulling it up a gentle slope).

The easy way to do this: If you need a length of rope $L$ to lower something on an incline, and a length $H$ to lower it vertically, then the force you need is lower by $\frac{H}{L}$. This is most easily confirmed by conservation of energy: force times distance needs to be the same.

You can do this with a vector diagram:

[image]

When the slope is 30 degrees, the force is exactly half (because $\sin(30°) = \frac12$)